# Gnome theme rejects Dark Theme selections, shows dark version but quickly switches back to light theme version on selection

Tags: gnome, appearance, gnome-tweaks

Fresh install with Gnome, got the themes how I wanted them (dark) then suspended the system and woke it back up to find that it was no longer in the dark variant of whatever theme I had selected, and by attempting to change to any dark theme it appears to work for a split second before being automatically reset to that version's default theme, both in appearance as well as the textual readout of the active theme in the Tweaks window.

The only strange things I had been up to were adding `.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` to reduce title bar size (which had no such effect on my last install of Gnome (Clear Linux)), but in an effort to troubleshoot this current issue that file was deleted which did not solve the issue.

I have also tried switching the theme in terminal with `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Adwaita-dark'` with the same results - the light theme variant is *switched to* immediately after execution.

Keep in mind that it isn't like it is simply being misdirected to the normal theme, it switches to the dark theme and switches back to its default version. It does not do this for the icon or shell theme options, only 'Applications.'

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Gnome layouts tool was applying a redundant dark mode which was screwing up the Gnome Tweaks settings. This solution fixed my issue perfectly.

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/dark-theme-not-applying-in-morning/28433